# Stored procedure INSERT from view into Table based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-update, sql-merge

My stored procedure calls an API which generates a consumable view of data. I need to insert the records from the generated view into local table.

So far, the procedure looks like below.

- The generated consumable view is `[vw_OriginalView_Temp]`
- Local table were data needs to be inserted is `LocalTable`. This table won't have any primary key.

Conditions for insert and update and skipping duplicates

- **SKIP** - if a record with exact combination of `CustomerGatcaStatusId, AccessNumber, AscertainMethodID, ExtendedStatusId, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy` exists in local table.
- **UPDATE** - if a record with exact combination of `CustomerGatcaStatusId, AccessNumber, AscertainMethodID, ExtendedStatusId` exists, then update the values of `LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy` with the values from the view `vw_OriginalView_Temp`
- **INSERT** - if any combination of `CustomerGatcaStatusId, AccessNumber, AscertainMethodID, ExtendedStatusId` doesn't already exist in `Local` table.

Please suggest and feel free to comment if you need further clarifications. Appreciate assistance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure1]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value INT,
            @RetCode INT,
            @RunID,
            @IntraDayID INT

    SET @RunID = NULL
    SET @IntraDayID = NULL

    EXEC @return_value = [Staging].[API_GenerateTempView]
                           @SchemaName = N'XXXX',
                           @ViewName = N'vw_OriginalView',
                           @ColumnList = N'CustomerGatcaStatusId, AccessNumber, AscertainMethodID, ExtendedStatusId, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy',
                           @OrderByList = NULL,
                           @ResultSet = 1,                           
                           @RunID = @RunID,
                           @IntraDayID = @IntraDayID,
                           @RetCode = @RetCode OUTPUT


    INSERT INTO LocalTable(CustomerGatcaStatusId, AccessNumber, AscertainMethodId, ExtendedStatusId, LastModifiedDate, StatusCode, LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy)
       SELECT 
           CustomerGatcaStatusId, AccessNumber, AscertainMethodId, 
           ExtendedStatusId, LastModifiedDate, '11', LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy 
       FROM 
           [XXXX].[vw_OriginalView_Temp]

    --IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AeoiSdtTemp)
    --BEGIN
    --  DELETE FROM AeoiSdtTemp
    --END
END
```

Comment: You might find the MERGE statement useful: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @pm_2 exactly, i believe merge statement will be useful, just trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like for the insert

```
INSERT INTO LocalTable(...)
SELECT (...) FROM [XXXX].[vw_OriginalView_Temp] _Temp left 
outer join LocalTable _Local on _Temp.a = _Local.a and _Temp.b = _Local.b 
where _Local.a is null and _Local.b is null
```

and for the update

```
UPDATE _Local
SET _Local.c = _Temp.c, _Local.d = _Temp.d
FROM LocalTable _Local 
left outer join TempTable _Temp on _Temp.a = _Local.a and _Temp.b = _Local.b and _Temp.c = _Local.c and _Temp.d = _Local.d
where _Temp.a is not null and _Temp.b is not null and _Temp.c IS NULL and _Temp.d IS NULL
```

untested but I guess you get the idea?

For the insert, doing a left outer join and testing for NULL checks that there is no existing record matching this condition
For the update we use the same mechanism but sometimes ensure NULL, sometimes NOT NULL to make sure we have a record partially matching